# Count if multiple columns and transpose columns in rows - PYTHON

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
A            B         C
Not info     XX        Not info
XX           YY        Not info
YY           ZZ        Not info
```

And I wanto to count "Not info" in all columns, but I also want it in row format. For the dataframe above, this is the output I want

```
Column_name     Count_not_info
A               1
B               0
C               3
```

ps: should be similar to what we get when we do dataframe.isna().sum().reset_index()

Does someone know how to do it in python? Tks a lot!

Comment: I do not understand how you got this output from this input

Comment: I didn't, that's what I'm asking

Comment: Sorry, I need to rephrase my comment:
"I do not understand the logic behind getting this output from this input"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by `isin()` method and boolean masking:

```
result=df[df.isin(['Not info'])].count().reset_index()
```

Finally:

```
result.columns=['Column_name','Count_not_info']
```

Now If you print `result` you will get your desired output:

```
    Column_name     Count_not_info
0        A                  1
1        B                  0
2        C                  3
```

Comment: If you wish, please consider accepting the answer to signal others that the issue is resolved (and also to keep people here motivated in helping others)...Thanks **:)**